# django запрос к БД

Tags: python, django

Нужно сделать следующий запрос к БД:

```
   SELECT s.id,count(s.id) FROM staff AS s
   JOIN tasks AS t ON t.author_id = s.id
   WHERE status_id IN(1,2) AND date_creation > '2015-01-01'
   GROUP BY s.id;
```

Как сделать это средствами моделей django?

Comment: Ваши таблицы staff и tasks привязаны к моделям django?

Comment: Непонятно, к какой модели относится условие из  блока `WHERE`, добавьте ваши модели в вопрос

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Если модели выглядят примерно так:

```
class Staff(models.Model):
    # ...

class Task(models.Model):
    staff = models.ForeignKey(Staff)
    status = models.ForeignKey(Status)
    date_creation = models.DateField()
```

Тогда:

```
import datetime
from django.db.models import Count

Staff.objects.filter(
    task__status_id__in=[1, 2],
    task__date_creation__gt=datetime.date(2015, 1, 1)
).values('id').annotate(Count('id'))  # или annotate(num_tasks=Count('id'))
```